# Page loads only after pressing enter twice

Tags: angular, url, dns

I have a SPA application in angular2. I see my view loads only when I hit enter twice after giving the url. Does anyone has any idea about this.

Comment: sounds like a browser setting rather than an Angular issue

Comment: That's not enough information. Any error in the browser console? What happens after the first enter? Where do you load your application from? ...